# specflow + xunit .. trying to skip testing in .net core

Tags: specflow, xunit.net

I'm trying to skip tests under certain conditions and this is what I'm doing.

```
    public static void BeforeScenario(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        if (scenarioContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("scenarioContext");
        string title = scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title;
        if (shouldSkipTest(title))
        {
            var unitTestRuntimeProvider = (IUnitTestRuntimeProvider)scenarioContext.GetBindingInstance(typeof(IUnitTestRuntimeProvider));
            unitTestRuntimeProvider.TestIgnore("Ignore in rd");
        }            
    }
```

I'm getting Xunit.SkipException ...  I tried TestInconclusive and TestPending, but they throw similar exceptions. Not sure what the correct way of skipping tests is. Any help would be very appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Since SpecFlow 3.1 we are using [xUnit.SkipableFacts](https://github.com/AArnott/Xunit.SkippableFact) when you are using xUnit.

You are able to use the API of it to skip scenarios.
Like

```cs
Skip.IfNot(Environment.IsWindows);
```

Btw, the BeforeScenario Hook method doesn't need to be static. This is only required for Before/AfterTestRun and Before/AfterFeature hooks.

---

Full disclosure: I am the community manager and a maintainer of SpecFlow and SpecFlow+

Comment: Thank you so much @Andreas Willich. However, I'm still getting Xunit.SkipException from Skip.If(). I'm using specflow 3.3.30.

Comment: Ok, I tried it out. It is working in step definitions, but not in hooks. I created an issue for this: https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues/2059

Comment: Thank you so much Andreas! BTW, what do you mean by "working in step definitions"? Step functions annotated with [Given], [When] .. ?  If correct and Skip.if(true) is called in my Given function, the whole scenario is skipped?

Comment: I called Skip in my [Given] function, but still got the SkipException ...

Comment: I added an example for skipping https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow-Examples/tree/master/xUnit/SkipScenario
Did you provide a message to the Skip.If(true, "message")? When I don't provide a message, I also get always the output "Exception of type 'Xunit.SkipException' was thrown"

Comment: Thanks a lot!  What I observed is ,, regardless 'message' is there or not, eventually looks like Skip working because I get a message like '3 Skipped', However, if I run in Debug mode, I always get Xunit.SkipExceptions .. so I have to uncheck 'Break when this exception type is user-unhandled ...' under Exception Settings.